# AsyncTaskの引数のvoidの意味を教えてください

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask

```java
public static class DownloadWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, void ,void {
    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return　null;
```

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask が取る型引数に指定されている Void の意味が知りたいのですね。

サンプルのコードはおそらく間違っています。以下が正と思われます。

```
public static class DownloadWorker extends AsyncTast<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

上記のコード中に Void は3箇所登場しました。最初の Void は *doInBackground*の引数の型に対応します。2番目の Void は *onProgressUpdate* というコールバックメソッドの引数の型に対応します。ちなみに、3番目の型引数は doInBackground の返り値の型と *onPostExecute* の引数の型に対応します。

以上を踏まえて上記のコードを解説します。まず最初の型引数が Void なので、 doInBackground の引数は Void となります。つまり doInBackground は引数を使った処理を行いません。2番目の型引数も Void なので onProgressUpdate の引数も Void となり、やはり引数を使った処理を行いません。3番目の型引数は String なので doInBackground は String を返します。

ここまで得られた知識を使うと Void 以外の型を設定した場合の実装ができるようになります。簡単ですが、例えば以下のコードです。

```
public static class DownloadWorker extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, List<String>> {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < uris.count; i++) {
          final String content = HttpClient.download(uri); // HTTP 通信をしてデータをダウンロードする。実装は省略
          publishProgress((int) i + 1 / uris.count) // タスクの進捗を整数で表現する
          list.add(content);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // ProgressBar とかに進捗を表示する
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
        // list を使って UI を更新する
    }
}
```

例外処理などは省略していますが、だいたいこんな感じです。AsyncTask  doInBackground 以外のメソッドは UI スレッドで実行される前提で作られています。そのため、型引数の仕組みを使ってスレッド間通信のコードをプログラマが実装することなく実現できます。

細かいことはリファレンスを参照してください。[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)